# "Cannot find pattern" when using a tagged union type

Tags: elm

I [have an app](http://github.com/anicholson/elm-hangman) that spans multiple modules. In the first, I model my problem, creating several data types. In the second, I'm putting views.

One of those types is a tagged union type:

```
type alias Letter = Char
type GuessedLetter = Guessed Letter | Unguessed
```

In my View module, I have a function for displaying a letter:

```
guessToChar : GuessedLetter -> Char
guessToChar guess =
  case guess of
    Guessed l -> l
    Unguessed -> '_'
```

But when I try compiling these files, I get the following error:

```
## ERRORS in src/Views.elm #####################################################

-- NAMING ERROR -------------------------------------------------- src/Views.elm

Cannot find pattern `Guessed`

21|       Guessed l -> l
          ^^^^^^^^^

-- NAMING ERROR -------------------------------------------------- src/Views.elm

Cannot find pattern `Unguessed`

22|       Unguessed -> '_'
          ^^^^^^^^^

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

I thought "Maybe I should export the tags as well as the type?", but neither *adding the tags to the module exports* nor *attempting to fully-qualify the tags* (`GuessedLetter.Guessed`) has resolved the issue.

How do I fix this function?

Comment: Can you provide the start of each files to your question? Both the module exports (`module <name>(<exports>) where`) and the imports in each module (`import <name>`) are going to be useful to debug this.

Comment: @Apanatshka I think I found it - see answer below…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I suspected, **if you want to use the tags outside the module, you have to export them too**. (I just wan't sure how).

To do that, add the tags in a comma-separated list inside parentheses.

From [the source code for `Maybe`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/4.0.0/src/Maybe.elm) (a type that 'worked' the way I wanted mine to):

```
module Maybe exposing
  ( Maybe(Just,Nothing)
  , andThen
  , map, map2, map3, map4, map5
  , withDefault
  , oneOf
  )
```

Or in my case:

`module Game exposing (Letter, GuessedLetter(Guessed, Unguessed))`

On the importing side, you can then choose to **fully-qualify the tags** (with the *module*, not the *type*):

```
import Game exposing GuessedLetter
{- ... -}

guessToChar : GuessedLetter -> Char
guessToChar guess =
  case guess of
    Game.Guessed l -> l
    Game.Unguessed -> '_'
```

or **expose the tags too**:

```
import Game exposing GuessedLetter(Guessed, Unguessed)
{- ... -}

guessToChar : GuessedLetter -> Char
guessToChar guess =
  case guess of
    Guessed l -> l
    Unguessed -> '_'
```